# How to capture photo from camera using appium in webdriverio?

Tags: javascript, android, appium, webdriver-io

I am using a sample application which enables to redirect to camera and I want to capture the image from the camera what can be done so that I automate the particular scenario using `appium` `webdriverio` in ANDROID devices .

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Appium Inspector? I have a test that takes a photo and I get the element "com.android.camera2:id/shutter_button". I guess depending on the camara interficie would be one or another.

Comment: yes i tried using xpath  value--  `//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Shutter']`

Comment: No id? that's weird coming from Android itself. I can get the same xpath, but in my case I also have an id. Can you try with it?

Comment: I tried with the id "com.android.camera2:id/shutter_button" but it showed up the error Appium error: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session

Answer (score 0):

In appium inspector you can find xpath for camera button. Im using Android Virtual Device and my path is :

```
let el2 = await this.driver.$(`//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc="Shutter"]`)
```

It's important to change context to "NATIVE_APP"

```
driver.switchContext("NATIVE_APP")
```